# I need to provide a XML file so my Android can fetch it

Tags: php, xml, phpmyadmin

I really am trying to code from PHP to have a XML file. I got the code that can display items from PHPmyadmin. but how can I display those things in XML file is really my problem, I tried all the codes. I could find. But, still no luck.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Answer (score 0):

While generating xml your first line in php file should be

> header ("content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");

then use echo statement & print whatever you want within xml tags like

> echo "<status>0</status>";

just follow xml standerds & test using IE will be better.

Comment: I tried to write that, but the contents don't appear in ".xml" file  (fopen). and can a php file displaying xml format can be used in parsing info on Android phones?

Comment: when you are calling this php file in your android program content is displayed by php file that will be response for your query now you can save this in .xml file & you can continue...